# xcode parse issue: Module webview_fltter_wkwebview not found

Tags: flutter, webview, webview-flutter

Use vscode to compile flutter app with webview on mac,run it in ios simulator,it's normal,
and I have added "io.flutter.embedded_views_previewYES" in ios's Info.plist,I am sure I have installed "webview_flutter" plugin,
but when I run it in xcode,always appears "Module webview_flutter_wkwebview" not found,
till now,I cound not solve the problem,please help,thanks!

Comment: have you tried `flutter clean` ?

Comment: I have run ""fluter clean" many times.bit the issue still exist~

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/657

I managed to make it work by opening Runner.xcworkspace instead of Runner.xcodeproj